# How to read Csv file in different folder

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit5

I am getting "Classpath resource does not exist" exception while using @CsvFileSource. The file is present in data folder but it getting normal when placed in resources folder. Where did I get wrong with the file path?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class ReadCsv {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/Selenium/ThucHanhSelenium/Wordpress/data/LoginTestWordpress.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
//    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/LoginTestWordpress.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)

    void loginInfo(String username, String password){
        System.out.printf("username" + username);
        System.out.printf("password" + password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the juni5t API there some clues about how to use that annotation :
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvFileSource.html
And I think it's suppose to be in resources folder.

On the other hand,
have you tried to change the **resources** word by your preference folder path for instance? here:

```
@CsvFileSource(**resources** = "/Selenium/ThucHanhSelenium/Wordpress/data/LoginTestWordpress.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
```